# Log4j2 Servlet 3.0 not logging

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, log4j2

I have a JAX-RS 2.0 application running on a Tomcat 7 server, and I'm using log4j2 along with SLF4J to record the server logs to a file.

I can't seem to get any logs to show up properly in my log file when running the server in production, although when I run my integration tests, logs are output correctly.

In production, the logs are merely redirected to the console instead.

My log4j2.xml file is located in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, and I've included all the necessary dependencies as well.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="file" fileName="log/trace.log" append="true" filePattern="log/trace.%i.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %X %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="my.package" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="WARN">
        <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The `web.xml` needs no configuration (I'm following the documentation found on the log4j2 website).

**EDIT**
I've tried setting the `Root` level to `TRACE` but everything still gets redirected to console. The file `log/trace.log` itself is created, it's just never written to. I also tried setting `immediateFlush=true` but that didn't have any impact either.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have status logging (log4j internal logging) set to TRACE. This will dump log4j internal initialization messages to the console. It this what you mean?

Otherwise, the config you provide shows there is no logger that has an appender-ref pointing to the ConsoleAppender. 
So, if you are also seeing your application logs being output to the console (in addition to log4j's status log messages), I suspect there is *another* log4j2.xml (or log4j2-test.xml) config file in the classpath somewhere.

Fortunately log4j's status logs should also show the location of the log4j config file, so you can confirm which config file is actually being loaded. 
You can switch off status logging by setting  `<Configuration status="WARN">` after confirming all works correctly.

Comment: hmm that's the thing, there ISN'T another log4j2.xml anywhere in the directory structure, so I still don't know why the output is going straight to console. 

A log file is created, it's just never appended to.

Comment: The log4j's status logs print to the console. This includes the location of the loaded log4j config file. Is that location correct? To help determine the cause, can you add the output of the log4j status log? This should show if there are any initialization problems.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Turns out I was using the `gretty` plug-in with `gradle`, which contains it's own logging package (the logback library).

It used it's own internal `logback.xml` which was redirecting to console. I fixed this by overwriting the internal `logback.xml` with my own (using `logback`'s configuration) and now everything works as expected!

Comment: This problem was reported as [Gretty issue](https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/120) and is now fixed.
Tomorrow I'll issue Gretty release 1.1.9, it will contain the fix.